# how to run flutter test on specific directory only?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

let say inside a test folder, I have structure like this

```
test
 unit_test
    firebase_services
       firestore_user_services_test.dart
    http_services
       http_services_test.dart
    

 widget_test
     login_page_test.dart 
     home_page_test.dart
```

I have two folders called `unit_test` and `widget_test` inside the test folder. I need to run all the tests inside the `unit_test` only. how to do that ?

because if I run `flutter test` it will run all the tests inside the `test` folder. if I run `flutter test unit_test`, it doesn't run

Comment: https://dart.dev/tools/dart-test - they say: *"To control which tests run, you can add the paths to directories or files under the test directory:*" - i know it is about `dart test` but they say it should work for `flutter test` too, they also say: *"Another way to run a subset of tests is to use the --name (-n), --tags (-t), or --exclude-tags (-x) flag, adding part or all of the string to match:"*

Answer (score 15):

I should run

```
flutter test test/unit_test
```

thanks to pskink to point out [this documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-test)